# What is this data format and how can I parse that do Java model

Tags: java, dataformat

I am using external api (Binance) to get prices for specific crypto symbol and I receive data in this format:

```
[   
    [
        1614556800000,
        "15.00700000",
        "15.38700000",
        "14.14100000",
        "14.37900000",
        "453842.30000000",
        1615161599999,
        "6709971.37110000",
        3535,
        "216741.30000000",
        "3217265.31930000",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        1615161600000,
        "14.43300000",
        "14.85900000",
        "14.05000000",
        "14.29200000",
        "539248.70000000",
        1615766399999,
        "7792792.20870000",
        3549,
        "278787.20000000",
        "4045258.39210000",
        "0"
    ]
]
```

And also the api has explanations what each value means. I tried creating Java model for those fields and parse them using RestTemplate but it doesn't work.

```
PriceChange[] priceChangeArray = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, PriceChange[].class);
```

I was expecting JSON format on this API cause other endpoints returns values using such format. I am asking that question cause I wanted to avoid creating parser for that.

**EDIT:**

Fields explanation:

```
  [
    1499040000000,      // Open time
    "0.01634790",       // Open
    "0.80000000",       // High
    "0.01575800",       // Low
    "0.01577100",       // Close
    "148976.11427815",  // Volume
    1499644799999,      // Close time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
    308,                // Number of trades
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "17928899.62484339" // Ignore.
  ]
```

PriceChange.java

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PriceChangeKey.class)
public class PriceChange {
    @Id
    private String symbol;

    private String interval;

    @Id
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date openTime;

    @Id
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date closeTime;

    private Double open;
    private Double high;
    private Double low;
    private Double close;
    private Double volume;
    private Double quoteAssetVolume;
    private Integer numberOfTrades;
    private Double takerBuyBaseAssetVolume;
    private Double takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume;
    private Double ignore;
}
```

Comment: How does your PriceChange model look like?

Comment: Provide some info on the api explanation for each value.

Comment: I've edited question with additional info but Andreas's solutions is good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format *is* JSON, but not in a good layout for automatically parsing to POJOs.

Parse to `Object[][]`, then manually map the entries to POJOs.

```java
Object[][] data = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Object[][].class);
List<PriceChange> priceChanges = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object[] record : data) {
    priceChanges.add(new PriceChange(
            ((Number) record[0]).longValue(),
            new BigDecimal((String) record[1]),
            new BigDecimal((String) record[2]),
            new BigDecimal((String) record[3]),
            new BigDecimal((String) record[4]),
            new BigDecimal((String) record[5]),
            ((Number) record[6]).longValue(),
            new BigDecimal((String) record[7]),
            ((Number) record[8]).intValue(),
            new BigDecimal((String) record[9]),
            new BigDecimal((String) record[10]),
            new BigDecimal((String) record[11])));
}
```

Or use setter methods and whatever data type is appropriate.